# Non-integer topological invariants

Tags: topological-insulators

I am reading the lecture notes of Asboth on topological insulators. There he defines a topological invariant as an integer that does not change under adiabatic deformation of the parameters in the model.

But why do we restrict outselves to integers? Couldn't there exist interesting properties that are non-integer and still do not change under adiabatic deformation?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Comment: @Qmechanic http://optics.szfki.kfki.hu/~asboth/topins_course/book.pdf Page 15 of the book (not the pdf).

Comment: By integer, you basically mean non-dimensionalizing an observable would lead to an integer right?  Then you have the quantum hall in graphene which gives half integers compare to the integer quantum hall.

Answer (score 1):

We don't restrict ourselves to integer-valued topological invariants.

Indeed, for the *fractional* quantum Hall effect, the topological invariant is a rational number which is (supposedly) stable under deformations.

The problem however is that our understanding of the non-integer (or $\mathbb{Z}_2$) valued invariants is relatively poor in comparison. AFAIK there is no interpretation of the phases of the FQHE as the homotopy group or as the K-group of something.